# TypeScript cannot find class defined globaly

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have this file

**routing.ts**

```
class RouteConfig {
  // Some implementation
}
```

which I use like this

**app.module.ts**

```
angular.module("ApplicationsApp", [
    "ApplicationsApp.Services",
    "ApplicationsApp.Clients",
    "ApplicationsApp.Application"])
    .config(RouteConfig);
```

I then import both of the previous files using

**index.ts**

```
import "./scripts/routing.ts";
import "./scripts/app.module.ts"";
```

I'm using `webpack` and `ts-loader` and `index.ts` is one of the entry point. The build succeeds, but when I run it I get this error

```
app.module.ts:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: RouteConfig is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.module.ts:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 755a82fd7c11e301b6c1:676)
    at fn (bootstrap 755a82fd7c11e301b6c1:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.ts:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 755a82fd7c11e301b6c1:676)
    at fn (bootstrap 755a82fd7c11e301b6c1:87)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (events.js:302)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 755a82fd7c11e301b6c1:676)
    at logLevel (bootstrap 755a82fd7c11e301b6c1:722)
    at main.min.js:726
```

The configuration I give to `ts-loader` looks like

```
{
  configFile: paths.resolveOwn('config/tsconfig.json'),
  compilerOptions: {
    target: 'ES5',
    module: 'commonjs',
    moduleResolution: 'node',
    sourceMap: true,
    strict: true,
    typeRoots: [
      paths.resolveOwn('node_modules/@types'),
      paths.resolveApp('node_modules/@types')
    ]
  }
}
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong ? I looked at almost all the `tsconfig.json` options, but cannot find one that resolves my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The issue

In `routing.ts` you don't have any `export` neither `import`: for TypeScript, it is a *script*. But you use Webpack and you `import` it: for Webpack, `routing.ts` is a *module*. At compile time, the class `RouteConfig` is accessible globally and your program compiles. But, at run time, the class `RouteConfig` is not accessible globally.

## Solution 1: The old way, load `routing.js` as a script

You can compile `routing.ts` in a separate file `routing.js`. Then, in the HTML code, the compiled file must be load from a separate tag `<script src="scripts/routing.js">`.

In this solution, do not `import` the file `routing.ts` from a module bundled by Webpack. Just ensure in `tsconfig.json` it is accessible by the TypeScript compiler.

## Solution 2: The ugly way, manually declare `RouteConfig` as a global variable

You could do:

```
// routing.ts
class RouteConfig {
  // Some implementation
}
window["RouteConfig"] = RouteConfig;
```

Then, in `index.ts` you import `routing.ts`.

```
// index.ts
import "./scripts/routing.ts";
```

As a result, Webpack ensures `routing.ts` is executed. And your global variable becomes accessible at run time.

Notice: This solution is based on a misunderstanding. For Webpack and at run time, `routing.ts` is not a `script` but a module that declares a global variable. For TypeScript (at compile time) it is a script that ends with something wacky and unmanaged about `window`.

## Solution 3: The ES6 way, all modules, nothing global

In the ES6 way, do not create any global variable. All the code is in modules. First, you have to export your class:

```
// routing.ts
export default class RouteConfig {
  // Some implementation
}
```

Then, you can import it:

```
// index.ts
import RouteConfig from "./scripts/routing.ts";
```

A documentation on ES6 modules: [ES6 in Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/).

Comment: Yes, but if I do so, `routing.ts` will no longer be consider as a script but as a module. And scripts are supposed to be defined globally if I understood well

Comment: @ThomasThiebaud You use Webpack. Do you load `routing.js` from a separate `<script>` tag? If yes, then you must not write: `import "./scripts/routing.ts";` (it imports nothing because nothing is exported).

Comment: No, I do not have a separate <script> tag

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. Thanks a lot